# How do I get a Date from Milliseconds (since epoch)?

Tags: dart

I got *`1234567890123` milliseconds* from **[`DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/millisecondsSinceEpoch.html)**.

How do I get **`Fri Feb 13 2009 23:31:30`** in *UTC time* from that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`DateTime`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) has a *[constructor called **`DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch`**](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch.html)*.

```
DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(1234567890123, isUtc: true).toString();
```